# Remove all chars up to last known char C#

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have some string:

```
var s = "*%hello%my%name%is%Mike%HowAreYou";
```

The `Mike%HowAreYou` is changed from object to object.

I want to trim all the start up to the last `%` and get `HowAreYou`

How can I do that in the best way?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('%') + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way I know, but requires "using System.Linq":

```
s.Split('%').Last();
```

The other answer is of course alright.